# Not able to send media file via WhatsApp

Tags: file-transfer, whatsapp-messenger

I recently downloaded the CyanogenMod on my Galaxy S2 but I'm not able to send any music files via WhatsApp does anyone have a solution to this problem ??

The error message is "your music player does not support this option try with Android music player"

Comment: Could you describe the problem further? Which version of CyanogenMod are you using? Where is the music file located? What does Whatsapp do when you try to upload it? Have you attempted to narrow down the problem by trying to share the same music file via other apps?

Comment: i am using cyonegen mode jelly bean 4.3.1. the music is located in my music folder in my internal sd storage . i've tried to share music file via other apps yeah and it's working fine .i noticed a thing though when i tried to install whatsapp for the first time it said : you are currently using a custom rom .some feature may not work properly something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails and you cant get it fixed, you can try to manually navigate to where the music file is in your file system and share it to whatsapp from there. That should work.

Answer (score 2):

The music player that comes with CyanogenMod doesn't support selecting the music file to send.  As you mentioned in the comments, custom ROMs may prevent the use of some features, and in this case, sending music files doesn't work.

You could try another custom ROM or reverting back to the stock ROM to enable this feature.

Comment: can't I switch the default music player ? I mean use another one like downloading the google default player that come with jelly bean ?

Answer (score 0):

I just connected the mobile to laptop and vent to DCIM folder and cleared the cache folder and I disconnected from laptop and imm. after that I can able to send picture & media files..

Answer (score -1):

Use FileManager. Browser it from the App list (dotted icon). Is a white carpet. Once you found it, keep pushing filename with finger and wait until context menu opens. It should appear some action as "Send via Whatsapp" or Share...

Good luck.

Comment: If you're going to just recommend apps, you could include the links where they can be found.

Comment: My friend, FileManager comes with CM operating system... not link available. If you want source code you can google about compiling cyanogenmod. So, if you'r just to be angry, you can google it first.

Comment: The name is quite generic, so I didn't know if you meant CM's FileManager or some other third party file manager app. Since I didn't have CM installed at that time, I was unaware that it had a built in file manager, and just wanted to clarify, no anger intended.

Answer (score -2):

Download another music player like Google Play Music. It's working fine. It's just a problem of adaptibility. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help the OP send files via WhatsApp.